# Style declared in resourcedictionary is not applied to combobox

Tags: wpf, xaml

I have a resource dictionary as follows :

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type ComboBox}">
        <Setter Property="IsEditable" Value="True" />
    </Style>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

In my app.xaml :

```
<Application x:Class="Client.App"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             StartupUri="MainWindow.xaml">
    <Application.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/Resources/ComboBoxResourceDictionary.xaml" />
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

**Update:**

In my Page.xaml :

```
<Page.Resources>
    <Style TargetType={x:Type ComboBox}>
        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value"20" />
    </Style>
</Page.Resources>

<ComboBox....... />
```

But still combobox is not editable. Is there anything wrong in above mentioned code?

Comment: You created an entirely independent resource dictionary for one small style template?

Comment: No, I will add some styles in it. But for the simplicity of the question I have shown only small template.

Comment: @Vishal - Are you sure you haven't declared default style resource for comboBox in your Window/UserControl etc? It works fine in small sample app.

Comment: Yes, I have declared another style. Let me update my question with that style.

Comment: @RohitVats I have updated my question with another style used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have provided another default style under Page resources, *all comboboxes falling under page won't pick up style declared under App resources*.

You should **inherit the style declared under App** using **`BasedOn`** like this:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type ComboBox}"
       BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type ComboBox}}">
   <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="20"/>
</Style>
```